# Is there any taste/texture difference between refined vegetable oils at temperatues above melting point

Tags: oil, melting

I am making vegan cheese and it calls for a lot of refined coconut oil. I am wondering If I were to substitute out half the refined coconut oil for equal parts of another flavorless vegetable oil would it make a difference in taste or texture once it is melted. The rationale for using coconut oil is so that it is solid at room temperature like regular cheese, but I am only concerned about the final melted product.

Comment: I wouldn't; getting vegan "cheese" to work is an acrobatic act of food chemistry, and swapping out half the oil is liable to result in a greasy mess.

Comment: Yes, all vegetable oils have a tiny bit of smell or taste no matter how defined they are. Try comparing any of two by yourself. You'll feel the difference.